# Partial Views & ModelState.AddModelError

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, partial-views, modelstate

the source of `LoginRegister` view is like this :

```
@Html.Partial("authentication/_login")
@Html.Partial("authentication/_register")
```

and each child view has got a form with this syntax

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(**seperated-methods**, "Login")) 
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(false)
}
```

I send error(s) in postback whit this code

```
ModelState.AddModelError("", "**any-error-message**");
return View("authentication/LoginRegister", customized-data);
```

The point is , error message shows in both `partial views`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to tell the ModelState to which property this error refer to:

```
ModelState.AddModelError("PropertyName", "**any-error-message**");
```

Now it will be only in the

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.PropertyName)
```

If you don't specify the property name, the error will be considered global and get shown in every `ValidationSummary`.